# SciLab matrix assignment Invalid Index Error

Tags: matlab, scilab

I want to hide an image inside an big image using SciLab tools, following is the code snippet I am using

```
S1_diag = diag(s1);
S2_diag = diag(s2);

S1_diag(1:length(s1), :) = S2_diag(1:length(s1), :);
```

where s1 and s2 are image 1 and 2's singular diagonal matrix

The same code works in Matlab but generates an 'Invalid Index' error (21) in SciLab. What I am missing?

I am novice in SciLab syntax so couldn't understand how to address this in SciLab.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is no guarantee that scilab will work exactly like matlab. This is the main reason to stick to only one program if possible. However, any of [these](http://www.annigeri.in/2011/11/scilab-submatrix-operations.html) operations should work.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that the `length` command is not the same for Scilab and Matlab.

- in Matlab, `length` gives the maximum dimension of a matrix. So, for a 2-by-3 matrix it is 3.
- in Scilab, `length` gives the number of elements. So, for a 2-by-3 matrix it is 6.

Here's a little dictionary:

- Matlab's `length(A)` is the same as Scilab's `max(size(A))`
- Scilab's `length(A)` is the same as Matlab's `numel(A)`